# Confidence bounds for Weibull MTTF

Tags: confidence-interval, weibull-distribution

I have three times-to-failure (TTFs) as 28, 40, 43. I fit a Weibull distribution on the data, and want to calculate a 95% confidence interval for the mean-time-to-failure (MTTF).  Using `R` function `MRRw2p` from the `WeibullR` package, I get the values of `beta = 4.731` and `eta = 40.41`.  I use following formulae to get the mean and standard deviation in `R`:

```
mttf = eta * gamma(1/beta+1)

sigma = eta * sqrt(gamma(2/beta +1) - (gamma(1/beta +1))^2)
```

How do I calculate the confidence interval from here? Can I use the formula as used in normal distribution?